# Using rope & net for deck railing

Tags: deck, railing

I'm looking to make a deck railing similar to this idea. 1-1/2" unmanila (synthetic manila) rope, with netting. In case, there will be rope at the top and bottom of the net, but that's beside the point.

I'm unsure how to attach the rope at the final post. It could pass through the hole, with a knot to prevent it from slipping back. But with 1-1/2" rope, that would be a gigantic knot.

Ideally, the securing mechanism would be hidden inside the post. I'm thinking of somehow winding the rope and sinking two long screws through the post, biting right through the middle of the rope.

Any other suggestions?

[image: Rope railing]

Comment: Quite a few years back when diving we found a big net and rope we pulled up ~100’ and a friend made a deck rail he wrapped the rope around the first post ~3 times and used a conduit strap to anchor the end after getting the rope to the other end of the deck he got it snug and wrapped the pole and anchored with another conduit strap. After a month or so he had to tighten it up so un doing the strap and pulling tight did the trick, whatever you do be cautious if you decide to paint it , he used a paint that did not stick well to the fibers and it looked bad quickly but had enough to redo it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I want to make sure the net doesn't sag, but the idea of wrapping it a few times is solid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one piece of rope for both top and bottom. At the end posts, run the rope along the outside of the post from the top hole to the bottom hole. At some point (need not be the end) splice the rope.

Or: at the ends, drill the rope holes at 90 degrees to the line of the railing, and eye splice a loop through each hole. Ease the sharp edges of the hole in the direction of the railing.

Comment: There's no "right" or "wrong" answer to this question, but your second suggestion is both elegant and simple. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Fasten a large screw eye to the post:

[image]

Then feed the rope through to make a loop and fasten it to itself with a rope clamp:

[image]

Comment: Hadn't seen the rope clamps before, I'll check them out, thanks!